# Map `^[` or `<c-[>` in neovim (without mapping `<esc>`)

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

At least on nvim-qt, `<c-[>` or `^[` can't be mapped without mapping `<ESC>` as well (as it usually translates to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<esc>` is not translated like this in lua, so use lua to map esc to itself!

```
local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }
vim.keymap.set('n','<esc>','<esc>',opts)
```

Then:

```
nmap <c-[> <Plug>Lightspeed_S
```

I tried this only on nvim-qt + Windows.